# MSSQL Report Server reset all permissions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver

I'm currently running a Windows Server 2008-R2 with a MSSQL server and Reporting Services.

There are currently hundreds and hundreds of folders and reports, however the users all adjusted their security settings.

My question is: Can I reset all permissions on all folders and reports to have the same user permissions as the /Home folder without having to open them one by one?
Or reset all permissions, create new ones on the /Home folder and let the other folders and reports inherit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API or directly change the SSRS data.  The API is approved and safer.  This article has some links that should get you started.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9f1b807-0200-47c9-9ec6-dd5316db13cf/reset-all-security-policies?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this looks promising, however it does not provide me with a quick and easy solution. I will however build some tooling around this using the API. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm late to the party but I just found this post which helped me to resolve the issue.

**Background**

I was moving the SSRS (2016) App and Database from one domain forest to another. Updating the PolicyRoot was on the right track but you also have to update the PolicyID to that of the parent folder you want to mimic (or security of another folder). In my case, all the Domain1\ accounts couldn't be seen from the site within Domain2 so I tried to update the PolicyUsers and Users tables using another domain and/or group to no avail. So after reading this post and doing some testing, I was able to create a script that resets all of the subfolders and objects to that of the the parent folder. You just need to be able to set the permissions on the parent root folder within the SSRS Website.

------------- start script

Use [ReportServer]

Declare @PolicyID varchar(max)

-- this is the root folder, note the PolicyID Number

-- select PolicyID, PolicyRoot, * from Catalog where ParentID is null and PolicyRoot=1

Select @PolicyID = PolicyID from Catalog where ParentID is null

-- below line will reset all the security permissions of all the subfolders

update Catalog set PolicyID=@PolicyID, PolicyRoot = 0 where ParentID is not null

------------- end script

**NOTE**: Policy root of 0 means to inherit from policy id and 1 means it's unique

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on mass by editing the [Catalog] table within the ReportServer database.

I think if you set the [PolicyRoot] field to 0 the folder objects will inherit permissions from Home.

Start with this query and have a look at the contents of the table:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog]
WHERE
    [PolicyRoot] <> 0
    AND [Path] LIKE '/%' --get child folders
    AND [Type] = 1 -- just folders
```

I haven't tested this so advise **extreme caution** and definitely backup the database first.

Comment: I tried the query after making a backup, but it does not seem to update the permissions when I view them in the reporting service.

Comment: My SELECT query or a new UPDATE statement you've written?

Comment: I mean the update statement I've written of course, sorry for the vague comment.

`USE [ReportServer]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Catalog]
   SET [PolicyRoot] = 0
 WHERE ItemID IN
 ( "list of ID's"
 )
GO`

Comment: There must be something else in the database controlling this. I suggest using the API method in the other answer above then.